# PHP getting data from database and wanted to show in a <p>

Tags: php

```
$customernumber = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT CustomerNumber FROM Registration WHERE Name='$name'" );

if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql)) {
die('Error: '. mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
echo "<p>Dear $name, you are successfully registered into ShipOnline, and your customer number is $customernumber, which will be used to get into the system.</p>";

mysqli_close($dbconnect);
```

the customer number is not showing, how can i fix this problem?

thanks

Comment: In name variable ' (single quote) is missing

Comment: @pc-shooter Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in

Comment: That means you have two errors, one that pc-shooter has mentioned and one in the code that you have not shown us. We'd have to see your `mysqli_result` line

Comment: Another error is in `echo`. `$customernumber` is not int, it's object

Comment: query has been executed but not fetch the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fetch` for retrieve records from `DB`. Try like below

```
$customernumber = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT CustomerNumber as cus_no FROM Registration WHERE Name='$name'" );
if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql)) {
    die('Error: '. mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customernumber)) {
    $customer_number = $row['cus_no'];
}
echo "<p>Dear $name, you are successfully registered into ShipOnline, and your customer number is $customer_number, which will be used to get into the system.</p>";
mysqli_close($dbconnect);
```

Comment: If you only expect a single row, you shouldn't use `while`. Otherwise +1 though.

Comment: : Undefined index: customernumber

Comment: Be sure that your `DB table (Registration )` has a column with `CustomerNumber`.

Comment: @user3659034 my table has a column with CustomerNumber